# In Hibernate Does StatelessSession prevent filtering out duplicates when have an EAGER JOIN

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-4.x

I have a *Song* class containing a collection of *CoverArt*s

e.g

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name = "recNo")
private List<CoverArt> coverArts;
```

and am using Hibernate 4.3.11 and DB2 database and  I have this query for retrieving a list of Songs by their primary key together with their coverArt.

```
public static List<Song> getSongsWithCoverArtFromDatabase(Session session, List<Integer> ids)
    {
        try
        {
            Criteria c = session
                    .createCriteria(Song.class)
                    .setFetchMode("coverArts", FetchMode.JOIN)
                    .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
                    .add(Restrictions.in("recNo", ids));
            List<Song> songs = c.list();
            return songs;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MainWindow.logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed LoadSongToDatabase:" + e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Note we have set fetch mode to *JOIN* on the *coverArts* collection, and that we need to set s*etResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)*, otherwise if we had a song with two coverart records we would get two Song objects returned back. But when using *Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY* Hibernate would correctly return one Song containing two coverArts.

However I have just tried to do the same thing but using a StatelessSession. The reasoning being I am just trying to select data for creating a report and I want maximize speed and minimize memory consumption, however

```
   public static List<Song> getSongsWithCoverArtFromDatabase(StatelessSession session, List<Integer> ids)
    {
        try
        {
            Criteria c = session
                    .createCriteria(Song.class)
                    .setFetchMode("coverArts", FetchMode.JOIN)
                    .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
                    .add(Restrictions.in("recNo", ids));
            List<Song> songs = c.list();
            return songs;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MainWindow.logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed LoadSongToDatabase:" + e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

this seems to ignore the  .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY) ands returns duplicates rows.

Is this a known bug, how it meant to behave ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is shortcoming in the way `StatelessSessionImpl` is implemented in Hibernate, but a fix might be on the way too...

Clearly with the `FetchMode.JOIN`, the SQL query will be (left outer) joining across the two tables, so may return several rows per song.  Normally Hibernate resolves each row returned via its `PersistenceContext`.

If interested, you can see this in the Hibernate source for `Loader` [here](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/f96eb35f97f6fc67efc5af389f9e21915d8a722d/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/loader/Loader.java#L1555).  Then, depending on the type of `Session`, [SessionImpl.getEntityUsingInterceptor()](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/f96eb35f97f6fc67efc5af389f9e21915d8a722d/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/internal/SessionImpl.java#L623) talks to the `PersistenceContext`, but [StatelessSessionImpl.getEntityUsingInterceptor()](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/f432ecea687ce606144c8fca1f4fc7f1937e1c2a/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/internal/StatelessSessionImpl.java#L425) just returns null.  However there is a [later commit](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/f96eb35f97f6fc67efc5af389f9e21915d8a722d/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/internal/StatelessSessionImpl.java#L465) to this method that looks to do the right thing.  The commit is part of [HHH-11147](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11147), which says the fix versions are Hibernate 5.3.11 and 5.4.4 - not showing in the [Maven repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core) at the time of writing.

In the meantime, one fix would be to roll your own `ResultTransformer`.  This is a fairly 'to the point' example:

```
public class DistinctSongResultTransformer implements ResultTransformer {
    private ResultTransformer defaultTransformer = Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY;

    @Override
    public Object transformTuple(Object[] tuple, String[] aliases) {
        return defaultTransformer.transformTuple(tuple, aliases);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Override
    public List transformList(List collection) {
        Map<Integer, Song> distinctSongs = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        for (Object object : collection) {
            Song song = (Song) object;
            distinctSongs.putIfAbsent(song.getId(), song);
        }
        return new ArrayList<>(distinctSongs.values());
    }
}
```

The difference is that the normal `DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer` assumes there will only be a unique instance of the entity in the session - you can see the compare [here](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/f96eb35f97f6fc67efc5af389f9e21915d8a722d/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/transform/DistinctResultTransformer.java#L43).

Clearly there's room to make that example more reuseable too, particularly to abstract the `getId()`.

Comment: Thankyou for the detailed answer, what I dont understand is since HIbernate is meant to hide the database complexity if I have a object that has a one-many association why it doesnt just handle it by default anyway, the more I use Hibernate the more I am disapointed by it.

Comment: @PaulTaylor - In my experience most frameworks make easy things easier, but deviating from supported functionality a lot more difficult (probably we expect too much because the simple stuff is so easy). Hibernate is a classic example of this. For the same reason, most people i know have a love-hate relationship with it. :)

Comment: Yeah, but Im confused if Im doing something weird here since retrieving a list of objects with their associated 1:M using EAGER seems a pretty standard use case to me ?